# find top n numeric cells in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell, threshold

Hi I have a cell array 2 x 1000. the first column holds numeric (double) values, the second holds a string. i would like the find all cells in the first column that are above a certain value, and bring back the corresponding cells in the second column. I have tried strcamp and various others but obviously they are for strings. I also tried doing

```
sortrows(mycell(1,:));
```

so i could pick the first 50 rows off or whateever, but this didn't seem to order the cell array. but really i would like to specifiy a threshold on the first column of the cell array.

How do I do this?

thanks.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just separate columns, so have a numeric array and a cell array separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `C` is your cell array:

```
nums = [C{:,1}];
```

`{:}` converts `C` into a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) (so `{:,1}` only converts the first column) and then `[]` collects the results into a normal array. After that it's simple:

```
index = nums > Threshold;
C(index,:)
```

OR in a one liner:

```
C([C{:,1}] > Threshold, :) %// Or C([C{:,1}] > Threshold, 2) as Luis said
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `C(index,2)`